# EA Addin EA_OnContextItemModified

Tags: add-in, enterprise-architect

I created an addin in C#. I want to prevent elements that have Status "Approved" so that no field is modified/updated until that Status is changed from "Approved".
I tried with API below, from the method signature I understood that will get updates after, but didn't found any API/method to get a pre-event. (something like EA_OnPreContextItemModified)

```
public virtual void EA_OnContextItemModified(Repository repository, string guid, ObjectType ot)
{
    if (ot == ObjectType.otElement && repository != null)
    {
        var element = repository.GetElementByGuid(guid);
        if (element.Status == "Approved")
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot modify this element because is Approved! Please change the status before modify this element!");
        }
    }
}
```

For example with the API above if the element has status "Implemented" and user changes to "Approved", then inside the API I get status "Approved" and throws and exception to not let the database to update with new update. In this scenario I want to get the pre-event status of the object with status "Implemented" together with what will change and me to take the decision to allow or not, is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the event `EA_OnContextItemChanged`, to remember the last status of the element.

Then compare it to the status of the element in `EA_OnContextItemModified`.

A bit like the (VBScript) code below:

```
Dim contextName
Dim contextGUID
function EA_OnContextItemChanged(GUID, ot)
     if ot = otElement then
        Dim contextElement 
        set contextElement = Repository.GetElementByGuid(GUID)
        if not contextElement is nothing then
            contextName = contextElement.Name
            contextGUID = contextElement.ElementGUID
        end if
    end if
end function

function EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified(GUID, ot)
     'check if the name has been changed
     if GUID = contextGUID then
        Dim contextElement 
        set contextElement = Repository.GetElementByGuid(GUID)
        if contextName <> contextElement.Name then
            msgbox "Element with name '" & contextName & "' has been changed to '" & contextElement.Name & "'"
        end if
     end if
end function
```

The API doesn't offer a way to stop the change, so all you can do it undo it by overwriting it with the values you remembered.

Comment: It is a good solution. It is working to get the element before and after the modification of a field. Still method don't have a return bool to avoid a modification , for example to return false when the condition is met for that element to not be modified. I tried to use throw new Exception, but still element is updated. I'm thinking only for solution to go field by field and overwrite the modification from element catch in method EA_OnContextItemChanged.

Comment: Indeed, there's no way to stop the modification except undoing it from the previous state.